# Use protocol with constrained associated type as property in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

I'm trying to implement a datasource protocol with associated type

```
protocol DataSourceCompatible {
    associatedtype CellModel
    func cellModelForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CellModel
}
```

Protocol `AddressBookViewModelType` inherits from base protocol and constrains the associated value to another protocol

```
protocol AddressBookViewModelType: class, DataSourceCompatible where CellModel == AddressBookCellModelType {
}
```

`AddressBookViewModel` is a concrete implementation of `AddressBookViewModelType` protocol

```
class AddressBookViewModel: AddressBookViewModelType {
    func cellModelForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> AddressBookCellModelType {
        let contact = sectionedContacts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return AddressBookCellModel(contact: contact)
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine, however when I declare the viewmodel as a property on my viewcontroller, the compiler fails with `Protocol 'AddressBookViewModelType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

```
class AddressBookViewController: UIViewController {
    private var viewModel: AddressBookViewModelType!

    func configure(viewModel: AddressBookViewModelType) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
...
}
```

I remember seeing type erasure might solve the issue, but I'm not that familiar with type erasure concept. Is there a way to solve the issue?

Update:

> How are AddressBookCellModelType and AddressBookCellModel related here?

It's a struct implementing a protocol.

```
protocol AddressBookCellModelType {
    var name: String { get }
    var photo: UIImage? { get }
    var isInvited: Bool { get }
}

struct AddressBookCellModel: AddressBookCellModelType {
 ....
}
```

Comment: This is a very complex use of protocols. Mixing class inheritance, protocol-inhertiance, and PATs is filled with corner cases and surprises. Do you expect multiple implementations of AddressBookViewModelType? If not, start by reducing the number of protocols and eliminating as many PATs as possible, and focusing on generics, or just simple non-generic code if you don't *actually* have multiple types involved. Proactively making Swift highly generic (i.e. before you have clear requirements for it) is filled with sharp edges.

Comment: How are `AddressBookCellModelType` and `AddressBookCellModel` related here? That one definitely feels like an abuse of protocols (trying to use protocols to recreate class inheritance, which is not their intent).

Comment: @RobNapier, please see the update to the question

Comment: What purpose is `AddressBookCellModelType` providing in your code? What's do the implementations look like? It's costing you a lot of complexity, and it's hard to imagine what benefit it's providing. This feels like a protocol that exists purely for the sake of avoiding a concrete type, and that is always a mistake. A simple struct is a perfectly good type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my questions in the comments, looking at this code it looks like it would be exactly as flexible without adding `AddressBookCellModelType` or `AddressBookViewModelType`, and this would also get rid of the headaches, while still being generic over `DataSourceCompatible`.

```
// This protocol is fine and very useful for making reusable view controllers. Love it.
protocol DataSourceCompatible {
    associatedtype CellModel
    func cellModelForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CellModel
}

// No need for a protocol here. The struct is its own interface.
// This ensures value semantics, which were being lost behind the protocol
// (since a protocol does not promise value semantics)    
struct AddressBookCellModel {
    var name: String
    var photo: UIImage?
    var isInvited: Bool
}

// AddressBookViewModel conforms to DataSourceCompatible
// Its conformance sets CellModel to AddressBookCellModel without needing an extra protocol
class AddressBookViewModel: DataSourceCompatible {
    let sectionedContacts: [[AddressBookCellModel]] = []
    func cellModelForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> AddressBookCellModel {
        return sectionedContacts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }
}

class AddressBookViewController: UIViewController {
    private var viewModel: AddressBookViewModel!

    func configure(viewModel: AddressBookViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Doing it this way allows for a generic VC without introducing more pieces that required:

```
class DataSourceViewController<DataSource: DataSourceCompatible>: UIView {
    private var viewModel: DataSource.CellModel!

    func configure(viewModel: DataSource.CellModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}

let vc = DataSourceViewController<AddressBookViewModel>()
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation Rob, I hoped to resolve the issue without having to make the VC generic. Guess I need to cut down the number of abstractions as you suggested:)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried just using it as a generic, like the warning/error says:

```
class AddressBookViewController<T: AddressBookViewModelType> : UIViewController {
    private var viewModel: T!

    func configure(viewModel: T) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    ...
}
```

You'd need to initialise your controller with a property of variable `T` so the type can be inferred.

Answer (score -1):

It's just Swift specification that you cannot use 'protocol with associated type' as a type declaration. The reason is that the compiler can't know what the associated type will actually be at the compile time, which violates the "type-safety" of Swift.

The solution would be to use type-eraser like you said, or make the type generic.

Comment: downvote because there is no example, just a hint of the idea, which he already had (type-eraser)